# Using c# RestSharp to upload a file to GoogleCloudStorageBucket, but receiving Error of 'You must specify an object name' although I passed 'name'

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, restsharp

I'm using C# RESTSharp to upload a csv file to Google cloud bucket
The documentation of the request is:

1. Get an authorization access token from the OAuth 2.0 Playground. Configure the playground to use your own OAuth credentials. For instructions, see API authentication.
2. Use cURL to call the JSON API with a POST Object request:
   curl -X POST --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION 
   -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" 
   -H "Content-Type: OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE" 
   "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=OBJECT_NAME"
   Where:
   OBJECT_LOCATION is the local path to your object. For example, Desktop/dog.png.
   OAUTH2_TOKEN is the access token you generated in Step 1.
   OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE is the content type of the object. For example, image/png.
   BUCKET_NAME is the name of the bucket to which you are uploading your object. For example, my-bucket.
   OBJECT_NAME is the URL-encoded name you want to give your object. For example, pets/dog.png, URL-encoded as pets%2Fdog.png.

For my c# query, When I add  parameter 'name' to the baseurl like the following:

```
`var client = new RestClient("https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("uploadType", "media");
request.AddParameter("name", "Products.csv");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {_accessToken}");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");`
```

It returns a response saying BadRequest 'you must specify an object name' which I already defined in the request URL. (the accesstocken is correct)
I feel like when I run the program, it ignores the 'name' parameter
Has anybody got this issue before? Did I miss something here?
Thank you

I've verified my parameters/headers to match with the Documentation, but I haven't found out what I missed in my code
Besides, somehow when it runs, it ignores the parameter 'name' and saying 'you must specify an object name' which is already defined in the code
I feel like either it ignores the parameter 'name' or something in my query shifts the parameter 'name' to somewhere else
Could anyone have a look and show me what I miss/ do wrongly here, please?

Comment: You may try AddQueryParameter instead of AddParameter. If i recall correctly for a POST Parameters will end up in the Body not the Query. AddQueryParameter should always add them as Query Parameters.

Comment: Also, update your post (the question) as your `RestClient` example is incomplete (no body).

Comment: @Ralf, AddQueryParameter sorted the issue. Thank you!